# How to perform linear regression on a parameter that represents state/configuration of a machinery in a production process?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, data-cleaning, knime

I am trying to perform linear regression on a manufacturing process in order to determine the influencing parameters on a particular product. The thing is there are several production parameters, and among them, there are a few machineries that can have different configurations.

Lets assume machine 1 can be in 5 configurations, State1, State2, State3, State4 and State5, in increasing order of influence, that is, State5 will make machine faster than State4. Can I assign a numeric value to each state (1,2,3,4,5) as shown and perform regression or is it wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "state" of a machine seems to be a distinct mode of operation. In this case, it may be useful, to assign this "mode" as a factor (i.e. as "one hot" encoded binary features). By doing so, each "mode" would be a single intercept term in the model. You can add interaction terms of the "mode" with numeric features to further increase flexibility of the model.

**Here is a minimal demo:**

```
df = data.frame(y=c(2,3,6,12,5,7,6,8,7), x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), i=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))
plot(df$x[df$i==1], df$y[df$i==1], col="red",xlim = c(1,9))
points(df$x[df$i==2], df$y[df$i==2], col="black")
```

[image]

The red dots correspond to ("state") $i=1$, the black points to $i=2$. You can see that there is a different pattern in both cases.

Running a linear regression with $i$ as factor (dummy encoded / one-hot encoded with additional interaction term) yields:

```
summary(lm(y~as.factor(i)*x,data=df))

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)      -2.5000     1.6432  -1.521  0.18863   
as.factor(i)2     5.6000     3.4467   1.625  0.16515   
x                 3.3000     0.6000   5.500  0.00272 **
as.factor(i)2:x  -2.8000     0.7348  -3.810  0.01250 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.342 on 5 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8668,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7868 
F-statistic: 10.84 on 3 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.01255
```

When compared to a model where $i$ ("mode") is a linear (numeric) feature, you can see that a factor encoded "mode" with interaction term works much better. The reason is that the different patterns in $i$ (red vs. black) are captured better in the first model (with factor and interaction) compared to the second model.

```
summary(lm(y~x+i,data=df))

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   7.7667     2.9306   2.650   0.0380 *
x             1.4333     0.6248   2.294   0.0616 .
i            -5.6000     3.2465  -1.725   0.1353  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.42 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4799,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3066 
F-statistic: 2.769 on 2 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.1407
```

However, ultimately you need to try several models to find the best representation of the "mode".